Load more in React
I'm facing a bug not able to recognise where doing wrong, during my first loading pagNum = 0 is calling twice which is causing first 3 result repeating twice after that when scroll down pageNum= 1, pageNum = 2 all working perfectly.
I used python for my backend and mongo DB.
This is my code
import './App.css';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

const App = () => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
  const limit = 3;
  const [initialLoad, setInitialLoad] = useState(true); // New state to track initial load

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialLoad) {
      fetchVideos(page); // Initial load with page 0
      setInitialLoad(false); // Set initialLoad to false after initial fetch
    }
  }, [page, initialLoad]); // Include page and initialLoad in dependency array

  const fetchVideos = async (pageNum) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/videos?page=${pageNum}&limit=${limit}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('Fetched videos:', data);
      if (data.length > 0) {
        setVideos(prevVideos => [...prevVideos, ...data]);
        setPage(pageNum + 1);
      } else {
        setHasMore(false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching videos:', error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    if (loading || !hasMore) return;
    const lastVideo = document.querySelector('.video-list > .video-card:last-child');
    if (!lastVideo) return;
    const lastVideoOffset = lastVideo.offsetTop + lastVideo.clientHeight;
    const pageOffset = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;
    const bottomOffset = 20;

    if (pageOffset > lastVideoOffset - bottomOffset) {
      fetchVideos(page);
    }
  }, [loading, hasMore, page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScrollDebounced = debounce(() => {
      handleScroll();
    }, 300);

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScrollDebounced);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScrollDebounced);
  }, [handleScroll]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Music Reels</h1>
      <div className="video-list">
        {videos.map(video => (
          <div className="video-card" key={video._id}>
            <video controls autoPlay muted>
              <source src={video.video_link} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            <div className="video-info">
              <h2>{video.title}</h2>
              <p>{video.description}</p>
              <p>{new Date(video.uploaded_date).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
        {!loading && !hasMore && <p>No more videos</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

If someone can help me in this. :)

Well you can clean the useEffect a bit you are now using a variable for initalLoad you can get rid of that and use useEffect without condition:
useEffect(() => {
  fetchVideos(page); // Initial load with page 0
}, []);

This should fix your issue first you load with 0.. then in the fetchVideos you  raise the page numb by one and it gets triggered on scroll.
This is from the top of my head, if the issue persists I will try to run the code locally.
